# How to calculate execution time in milliseconds

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++, I need to print the execution time of my program in milliseconds with 4 digits (X.XXX) - I tried to use

```
double start_s=clock();
// my program here
double stop_s=clock();
cout << "time: " << (stop_s) << endl;
```

I got 0.
What am I doing wrong?
Btw I am using (and have to use, college project) VS2010, so chrono is not an option.

Comment: `clock` is very primitive. Use [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) instead.

Comment: There's no way the provided code gives this output.

Answer (score 19):

Use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/) from the [`chrono`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) header.

```
auto started = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
DoWork();
auto done = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(done-started).count();
```

You can also cast to `std::chrono::seconds` or `std::chrono::nanoseconds` if you wish.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.eriksmistad.no/measuring-runtime-in-milliseconds-using-the-c-11-chrono-library/) on measuring execution time with `chrono`.

---

**Edit:** if your compiler doesn't support `chrono`, then <strike>get a newer one</strike> take a look at `src/ptimer.c` in the source code of [`wget`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.17.tar.gz). It works on Windows and Linux and uses native API.

Comment: Another example is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/

Comment: @yasouser, yeah, I was just going to include this link as well.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 and can't find the chrono header. Does this make sense?

Comment: Just googled it and yep, VS2010 doesn't have the chrono header, unfortunately my college forces me to use VS 2010.

Comment: @Gilzy, does it have C++11 support?

Comment: Partly, It doesn't recognize the chrono header though.

Comment: @Gilzy, that's bad. Maybe your college wants you to learn some Windows API? All in all, you won't achieve such precision with neither `clock`, nor `time`.

Comment: @Gilzy, I think there is a solution. Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @yasouser That linked example is in seconds. it does not address the question